# Удалить дубликаты в массиве PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, массивы

Есть массив

```
[61] => Array ( [id] => 782 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 443 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[62] => Array ( [id] => 783 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 442 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[63] => Array ( [id] => 784 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 441 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[64] => Array ( [id] => 785 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 439 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[65] => Array ( [id] => 786 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 438 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[66] => Array ( [id] => 787 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 437 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[67] => Array ( [id] => 788 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 431 [id_tovarniy_class] => 51 ) 
[68] => Array ( [id] => 789 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 199 [id_tovarniy_class] => 52 ) 
[69] => Array ( [id] => 790 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 200 [id_tovarniy_class] => 52 ) 
[70] => Array ( [id] => 791 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 203 [id_tovarniy_class] => 54 ) 
[71] => Array ( [id] => 792 [id_product] => 13 [id_tovarniy_category] => 206 [id_tovarniy_class] => 54 ) )
```

Поле id_tovarniy_class имеет 3 значения (51, 52, 54). Как мне сделать так что бы дублированные элементы не показывались.

Данные получаю через таблицу MySql

```
Select *
From table
```

Где лучше сделать фильтрацию, на стороне БД или уже в готовом массиве?

Comment: что в итоге должно показываться?

Comment: В показанных данных **НЕТ** дубликатов. Хотя бы одно поле в каждой паре строк - различается. *Где лучше сделать фильтрацию, на стороне БД или уже в готовом массиве?* Обрабатывать данные нужно на сервере БД. На клиентской стороне производятся только форматные и нереляционные операции.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT id_tovarniy_category
From table
```

Оказывается все решается на стороне MySqk